In 4NCL are practically all players good enough to have FIDE rating?
In 4NCL (Four Nations Chess League) are practically all players good enough to have FIDE rating?
How quickly after starting to play in the lower league will a player have played 5 FIDE rated players?
(The Four Nations League is a team tournament over five divisions (one, two, three knights, three bishops, four), with over 850 players registered to take part and over £10,000 in cash prizes on offer. It is the most prestigious team chess event held in the United Kingdom)

The tournament is 11 rounds played over 5 weekends. The last round to be played as of 1st May 2024 is round 8. Here are the results for the 28 teams in division 4. The FIDE rating floor is 1400.
Where FIDE ratings are not available ECF ratings are used and when these are also not available an estimate is used. 20 out of the 168 players have ratings below 1400, so a very large majority have FIDE level ratings.
In division 3 knights one player is below 1400 and also in division 3 bishops one player is below 1400. These two divisions are supposed to be equivalent level divisions in the north and south of the country.

How quickly after starting to play in the lower league will a player have played 5 FIDE rated players?

12 of the 28 teams have sub 1400 level players on one or more of the bottom boards so if you play for a very weak team it might take several seasons. Play for one of the stronger teams and it might take only half a season.

I assume anyone who is good enough to get a fide rating is unlikey to always be on a bottom board in the bottom division.
